# Revalidate Model in Web API

Tags: c#, validation, asp.net-web-api, model, modelstate

I have model with fields below:

```
-Id : Required (database generated)
-Title : Required
-Status : Required
-Comments
```

When I run a post given this:

```
{
"title":"WOHOO",
"status":"STATUS"
}
```

Everything runs fine. However, when I run a post with the below:

```
{
"title":"WOHOO"
}
```

I get a model state issue because status is required. However, in my post method it is like this:

```
[Route(""), ResponseType(typeof(MyModel))]
public IHttpActionResult PostMyModel(MyModel model)
{
    // Save request in DB
    model.status = "Waiting";

    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return BadRequest(ModelState);
    }

    db.MyModels.Add(model);

    try
    {
        db.SaveChanges();
    }
    catch (DbUpdateException)
    {
        if (ModelExists(model.id))
        {
            return Conflict();
        }
        else
        {
            throw;
        }
    }

    return CreatedAtRoute("DisplayMyModel", new { id = model.id }, model);
}
```

I am setting the status at the start of this method, but the ModelState is as-is when the request starts. I can clear the ModelState with `ModelState.Clear()`, but then how do I revalidate the new model?

This is in an ApiController.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The correct way to approach this is to first clear the model state, then call the `Validate` method with the new model. This adds any validation errors to the model state. See below:

```
ModelState.Clear();
model.status = "Waiting";
Validate<MyModel>(model);

if(!ModelState.IsValid){

etc...
```

Comment: Controller doesn't have a method Validate<T>().  Where is that method defined?

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.controller_methods(v=vs.118).aspx

Comment: The syntax is now TryValidateModel(model);

Answer (score 0):

### One alternative (correct for security, but more tedious)

Use separate objects for model binding and database access.

In this it is pretty simple, but you might get into cases where overbinding is an issue, so from security perspective, you want a separate DTO to bind to, check the validation, and then add your updates and pass to the database.

See this [Link](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/data/using-web-api-with-entity-framework/part-5) for more reading.

### Alternatively

In your case, you can just remove the single error you are encountering (because it is well known) and then check ModelState.IsValid.

```
ModelState.Remove("status");

if (!ModelState.IsValid)
{
    ...
}
```

for deeply nested object you will save some significant processing for validation.

Comment: note that if you use [FromBody] your key for removal will be model.status